# When I publish it, it comes out after a few minutes using the serve in react js

Tags: reactjs

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open'C:\WEBSITES\gradient_mobinsbtraining\build\asset\images\homeImage\logoHome\image\logo-5.png'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
at internal/fs/streams.js:136:12
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23) {
errno: -4066,
code: 'EMFILE',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\WEBSITES\gradient_mobinsbtraining\build\asset\images\homeImage\logoHome\image\logo-5.png'